# coalesced read write on different part of the buffers

Tags: cuda

Let's say we have 32 threads. The first thread reads 128 bits (uint4) at offset 0, the second thread reads 128 bits at offset 16 and so one until the 32th thread reads 128 bits at offset 496. They all are coalesced into one read.

Now let's say that some threads read 128 bits values aligned on 16 bytes on an offset between 0 and 512 (16 bytes aligned) and other threads read 128 bits on an offset between 512 and 1024 (16 bytes aligned as well).

Do the access of the first part of the buffer is coalesced and the access of the second part is coalesced also resulting in two read.

Or are there 32 reads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be some number between 16 and 32 "reads" in the second case.  But we should be more careful with terminology, for understanding.

The *coalescing* process works as follows.

1. The LD/ST unit receives a **request**.  Let's assume we are talking about a read request (i.e. a LD instruction).  The read request constitutes the LD instruction plus the address generated by each thread in the warp.
2. The request is processed to determine the location of each address relative to the others, when viewed against cachelines or memory segments.  For this discussion, lets assume there are no hits in any cache, therefore we must rationalize the request against memory segments.   Memory segments are a fixed subdivision of the global memory space, corresponding to the minimum transaction size issuable to the DRAM subsystem.  On all CUDA GPUs I am familiar with, the memory/DRAM segment size is 32 bytes.  The mapping of the addresses generated by each thread in the warp against the DRAM segment pattern will identify which actual segments in memory must be retrieved to satisfy this LD request.
3. The memory controller will retrieve those segments.  For DRAM, each request to retrieve a segment is a **transaction**.
4. The retrieved segment data will be used to populate cachelines as appropriate, and also to satisfy the original LD request, warp-wide.

Coalescing basically occurs in step 2.  As the addresses issued across the warp are mapped to the underlying pattern of DRAM segments, if multiple addresses fall into a single segment, this segment will not be requested more than once.  It will only be requested once.  That is the central idea of coalescing.

Now, with the above description, let's look at your specific example(s).

In the first example, you state "they all are coalesced into one read".  Well they certainly started out as a single read request.  But the minimum number of 32-byte DRAM transactions to satisfy a non-overlapping full-warp read (32 threads) of 16 bytes per thread, is 512 bytes, or 512/32 = 16 segments.  Depending on where or how you are measuring this, it could also be referred to as 4 global transactions, since a global load transaction is up to 128 bytes wide.  But regardless of how/where we measure this, this would be a fully coalesced, 100% optimal set of transactions, because the minimum number of transactions needed to satisfy such a request are generated, and every byte retrieved from memory is used or at least requested by a thread in the warp.

In the second example, the precise activity cannot be determined without knowing the actual address pattern generated by the threads in the warp.  For the threads that read locations between 0 and 512, there are at most 512/32 = 16 segments in this range.  And there are 16 threads.   So you could be in a worst-case (for this particular arrangement) scenario where each thread requires its own segment.  Alternatively, if the thread addresses are not perfectly spaced at 32-byte boundaries, then the number of DRAM transactions needed for the first 16 threads could be lower than 16, possibly as low as 8.  Likewise for the second group of 16 threads, and the second group of 512 bytes in memory.

So for a best case pattern, only 16 transactions would be issued to DRAM for the 2nd example, exactly matching the first example in terms of the number of DRAM transactions generated, as well as the overall efficiency (100% utilization).  For the worst case pattern (each thread address spaced at 32-byte boundaries) then it would require 32 segments, and therefore 32 DRAM transactions, to satisfy the warp read request.

To give a code example, the following sequence would generate 32 DRAM transactions per warp:

```
__global__ void k(float4 *d){
  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  float4 temp = d[idx*2];
  ...
  }
```

In the above example, the underlying byte addresses generated by each thread would be perfectly spaced at 32-byte boundaries.  The first 16 threads would be requesting data from the first 512-byte area in memory, and the second 16 threads would be requesting data from the second 512-byte area in memory.  The overall efficiency of that request would be 50% (1024 bytes would be requested from memory, but only 512 bytes needed by the threads in the warp).

The following sequence would generate 16 DRAM transactions for the first warp:

```
__global__ void k(float4 *d){
  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  float4 temp = d[idx + (idx/16)*16];
  ...
  }
```

In the above example, the underlying byte addresses generated by each thread would be 0,16,32,48...,252 for the first 16 threads (in the first warp).  For the second 16 threads (in the first warp) the addresses would be 512,528,544....,764.  The first 16 threads would be requesting data from the first 512-byte area in memory, and the second 16 threads would be requesting data from the second 512-byte area in memory.  However the first 16 threads would only require 8 DRAM transactions, and the second 16 threads would only require 8 DRAM transactions.  The overall efficiency of that request would be 100% (512 bytes would be requested from memory, for the 512 bytes needed by the threads in the warp).

Comment: Your answer is amazing, however, what is a LD/ST? Load store?

Comment: Yes, load/store.  It's a functional unit inside the SM (Streaming Multiprocessor) of a CUDA GPU.   You can get a general introduction to CUDA GPU architecture by reading a whitepaper, such as [this one](https://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/product-specifications/GeForce_GTX_680_Whitepaper_FINAL.pdf).